# Can't change top panel color in gnome Linux mint 19

Tags: linux-mint, gnome, colors

I've installed gnome on my linux mint machine, and I want to change the default white of the top panel to another color. I installed and the `Activities Configurator` in which there are settings for that, however changing those settings did not alter the colors. This may relate to my other problem with the gnome window-list found here: [Remove Window List in Gnome (Mint 19)](https://superuser.com/questions/1432619/remove-window-list-in-gnome-mint-19)

How can I change the colors of the panel?

Edit: I also noticed that other settings to the panel, such as whether it shows on all displays, worked.

Comment: 1. Your other question mentions gnome-tweaks.  this one mentions unity-tweaks.  Can you clarify?  2. Gnome isn't offered as a pre-integrated DE on Mint.  Are you sure you installed all of the component packages?

Comment: Yes it’s gnome tweaks sorry